# Redirecting in express without change the URL

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I have 2 servers, lets say Server A and Server B and Server A is the server responsible by handling the requests and redirecting them to Server B when needed.
So, my question is, can I, in nodeJS redirect without changing the URL? I have this sample code running on 127.0.0.1 and another Apache Server running on 192.168.1.112.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const mRouter = express.Router();
mRouter.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
});

mRouter.get('/B', (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('http://192.168.1.112');
});

app.use('/', mRouter);

app.listen(80);
```

And the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <a href="/B">B Server</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link it redirects to the correct place, but also changes the URL to 'http://192.168.1.112', can I stop it from changing the URL?

**Edit:**
For example, I have Server A running on localhost and every request that goes to 127.0.0.1/B is requested from 192.168.1.112 (Server B). The problem is that Server B redirects to index.php/* and if I use a reverse proxy the path is put in the URL. Is there a way to remove the URL path from Server B?

Comment: Your server can't cause the browser to lie about the URL.  So a redirect will always show the actual URL.  You could have serverA proxy (instead of redirect) from serverB so the data from serverB was actually coming from serverA and then serverA would show in the URL because (as far as the browser is concerned), that data came from the serverA URL.

Comment: @jfriend00 How could I create such proxy using express? And I am aware of the URL content comes from ServerB, I just don't know how to get ride of it.

Comment: See my answer below for more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Your server can't cause the browser to lie about the URL (from server-side).  So a redirect will always show the actual URL.

You could, however, have serverA proxy (instead of redirect) from serverB so the data from serverB was actually coming from serverA and then serverA would show in the URL because (as far as the browser is concerned), that data came from the serverA URL.  When proxying, the browser would send a request to serverA, then in the act of processing the requeste serverA would realize that it needs some data from serverB, it would go get that data itself form serverB and then return that as the response to the original request to serverA.  The browser would just see it as a request from serverA (even though the data actually came from serverB).

To fetch data from serverB, serverA can just issue an http request using a library such as `request`.  You fetch the data from the other server using this http call and then return it as the result from the request you received.

```
const request = require('request');

mRouter.get('/B', (req, res, next) => {
    // get actual data from other server and return it as our response
    request('http://192.168.1.112/B').pipe(res);
});
```

As another option, from the client-side, if you were fetching the data via Ajax calls from a browser page, you could also see the redirect, go get the data from serverB and insert it into the serverA page.  Dynamically modifying the content of a page with browser Javascript does not change the URL.

Comment: @Simplecoder - This simple a code doesn't modify the content it gets from serverB.  If those links are relative (such as `href="/something"`), then those will be directed to serverA by the browser (since the browser doesn't know the content came from serverB).  If the links are absolute (such as `href="http://serverB.com/something"`), then those links point to serverB and clicking on them in the browser would go directly to serverB.  A more complicated proxy could attempt to "rewrite" all the links in the proxied content.

Comment: I tried to create a reverse proxy, but has the same problem: it replaces the url path with the other's server path, I tried to rewrite the url afterwards with req.url and app.handle, but didn't work

Comment: @Simplecoder - If you described the actual product situation you're trying to solve with higher level details (rather than just this lower level technical discussion), we might be able to offer other ideas.

Comment: I have an Apache Server on 192.168.1.112 that redirects any requests from the root to /index.php/login or /index.php/apps, and i need to create a Server using nodeJS that redirects the request to this server, but I don't want the /index.php/* to appear on the url bar. I tried using http-proxy, but I am not getting it to work

Comment: @Simplecoder - Well, I don't know the Apache world, but this is not a unique problem and if you ask a new question where you explain this level of the problem with more detail, there are probably others who can help.  You're always much better off if you start off describing the real, top-level problem, not just issues with the particular solution you are attempting.  That lets people offer you bigger picture solutions than just what you have thought of.

Comment: But this is not a problem with Apache. The Apache server is working without problems, what doesn't work is nodeJS end.

Comment: @Simplecoder - The whole solution involves Apache and what you're trying to do (rewrite URLs) is not an uncommon problem with that setup.  I'm not going to argue with you here.  I suggested a way you may get a lot more people to offer you higher level answers than the solution path you're down right now.  If you don't want to pursue that, it's up to you.